# Setting specific colors in google charts

Tags: charts

I have Google visualization where I want to set the specific colors of each pie slice/bar based on a column in the datatable.

i.e. I have a table of the number of people who voted for their favorite color:

```
*Input table*
id  Color   Num Votes
1  'Red'    10
2  'Blue'   100
3  'Green'  50
```

How do I set the colors on the pie chart so that the slice for 'Red' is colored red, etc? However, due to the data set, I cannot guarantee that the rows will be in a certain order so cannot create an array of colors.

I think I need to use a formatter, but cannot get it to work.

```
 var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
 formatter.addRange('Blue', 'Blue', 'blue', 'blue');
 formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

Easy,

Just set it on `var options`

it should be like this:

```
var options = {'title':'Your Title',
               'width':XXX,
               'height':XXX,
               colors:['Blue', 'Blue', 'blue', 'blue']};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the options via the second parameter of the draw() method.

```
var chartOptions = {
    title: 'My Awesome Chart',
    colors: ['#657CD0','#DA68A0','#06C3C0','#777B80','#7C6D70','#7C0850','#F75870']
};

var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart'));
pieChart.draw(someData, chartOptions);
```

Check out this color picker for Google Visualization: http://www.philipwhitt.com/projects/google-visualization-theme-picker, it might give you some useful color ideas.