# How to change the percentage to different color

Tags: google-visualization

I am doing a google chart that displays percentage data.

I have got it working already.

The question is the percentage displayed on the chart is white in color which cant be seen clearly. How can i change the color of it to black and if possible individual color for each section.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959984/setting-specific-colors-in-google-charts?rq=1

Comment: Its not the color of the slice, its the percentage displayed on it which is all white.